# Camel, how to delete-only file on smb share?

Tags: apache-camel, smb

I want to delete only file(s) on a smb share with

```
<pollEnrich>
    <simple>smb://{{uri}}&amp;fileName=${header.ResultFileName}&amp;delete=true&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1</simple>
</pollEnrich>
```

but it gives Out of memory error (perhaps because it tries to receive the file, and file size is over 1GB).

This method is working well on sftp using download=false option.
How can I obtain the same result (just delete a given file) with smb?

Thanks in advance.

Camel v2.20.1
camel-jcifs v2.18.0
jcifs v1.3.17
The camel runs on Linux and connects to a win smb share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the source of (camel-jcifs, org.apache-extras.camel-extra) and found that there is already a "download=false" option (like FTP), which solved my problem.

It seems this is a lack of documentation.